# Where can I find data member of std::bitset?

Tags: c++

When I read the [bitset page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) on cppreference, I tried to find some *data memeber* column to see how the data is stored. I found that there's no such column and neither another std class such as `std:string`. Then I go to https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/bitset, check the *bitset synopsis* comment part, and there's nothing I can't find about its data member. Why? What do I miss here? An example of any std classes would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because they are private so you don't need to know about them? They are not part of the interface.

Comment: It might help to know your motivation here. I don't think the private implementation of these classes is important, so are you simply curious or is there something you're trying to get out of this?

Comment: @Tas Just out of curiosity. When I try to understand a class, I usually check its data member first.

Comment: @Rick: You should stop doing that. If you want to understand a class, look at its *documentation* first, not how it gets implemented. Look at the interface it provides, not the interface it *hides*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok I will keep that in mind. I was just curious about that.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's the theory, in practice human mind generally works going from concrete to abstract, not the other way around. Seeing an implementation often helps understand what you are actually dealing with and fix the guarantees provided by the standard in memory, while going the other way around requires sending to memory a lot of apparently random rules. Having a solid understanding of how the standard containers can be implemented IMO is crucial to develop an intuitive understanding of how to use them effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the libcxx implementation, The following protected data member is how the real bits are implemented.

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/bitset#L163

```
template <size_t _N_words, size_t _Size>
class __bitset {
public:
  typedef size_t __storage_type;
  // ...
protected:
  // ...
  __storage_type __first_[_N_words]; // <========= the data
};

// ...

template <size_t _Size>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS bitset
    : private __bitset<
          _Size == 0 ? 0 : (_Size - 1) / (sizeof(size_t) * CHAR_BIT) + 1, _Size>
{ /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 7):

CppReference documents the public interface, which is the only thing the standard mandates and that you are supposed to care about.

Same for the synopsis of the libc++ header: it's just a copy-paste from the standard, probably put there as a reference for the library implementors. You can find the nitty-gritty details of the implementation below.

Data members of STL containers are implementation details you are not supposed to care about and subject to change, both between the various standard libraries implementations, as well as for different versions of the same library or even different  compilation flags.